# You Cannot Bind The Submit Event To Objects Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

According to 
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1892-You-Cannot-Bind-The-Submit-Event-To-Objects-Using-jQuery.htm

It is a bug:

"I am pretty sure this is a bug; jQuery is probably supposed to be checking the type of the object in the binding before it attempts to use it as a DOM node. "

Is it or is it not according to you ? If yes has this been fixed and in what jquery version.

Comment: Regardless of the answer by jprofitt, a statement followed by an opinion poll seems sort of out of place for StackOverflow. I could be wrong, but I usually expect to see specific programming questions. "I need to bind the submit event to an object, but I can't. There seems to be a bug, but does anyone know how I can accomplish this?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments on that article included a [link to a bug ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6398) that indicates it was fixed 13 months ago.